# programme is running infinitely in jumpsearch

Tags: javascript

```
arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233 ] 

const JumpSearch = (arr, num) => {
    const length = arr.length;
    const eachBlock = Math.floor(length/4);
    let index    = 0;
    while(index < length){
        let temp    = arr[index];
        if(num < temp){
            //search left
            index = index - 1;
        } else if(num === temp) {
            //matched return this
            return true
        } else {
            // jump eachBlock  
            index = index + eachBlock;
        }
    }
    return false;

} // O(√4)

console.log(JumpSearch(arr, 14))
```

Here i am trying to implement [**JumpSearch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search) in javascript.
It is sometimes coming stay running the else block infinitely if the 
result is not matching.

PLease have a look.

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: What is "jumpsearch"?  It's not clear what you expect this function to do.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jump-search/ please check this?

Comment: Yes the array is always sorted.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Don't downvote my question if you don't know what is jumpsearch algorithm.

Comment: How is that an implementation of a jump search?

Comment: `JumpSearch([15], 14)` already goes into an infinite loop. You should be able to follow the process with pen and paper. See e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is correct, basically adapted from the PHP code.  You could actually pass in the interval.  They say the square root of the array length is optimal.  The first loop get the interval and returns -1 if num is not in an interval.  The second loop starts at the beginning of the interval increments the index by 1 starting at the beginning of the interval until the end of the interval is reached of the end of the array is reached.  Seems to work.

```js
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233];

const JumpSearch = (arr, num) => {
  const length = arr.length;
  const interval = 3;
  let current = interval;
  let prev = 0;

  while (arr[Math.min(current, length) - 1] < num) {

    prev = current;
    current += interval;
    if (prev >= length) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  while (arr[prev] < num) {
    prev++;

    // If we reached next block or end of 
    // array, element is not present. 
    if (prev == Math.min(current, length)) return -1;
  }
  // If element is found 
  if (arr[prev] == num) return prev;
  else return -1;
}

console.log(JumpSearch(arr, 21));
```

Comment: Interesting that your array is the Fibonacci series.  There is apparently a search technique related to that.